# pushing data into stack, assenbly

Tags: variables, assembly, stack

Why is it that lenght can be pushed directly unto the stack while message has to be copied to a register and then pushed unto the stack?

Why is the string declared as a byte while 11 is defined as a word?

```
 message:db'hello world'
 length:dw 11


 mov ax, message
 push ax
 push word [length]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do `push message` directly, but the exact syntax for this is often assembler-specific. You may need to write `push offset message` instead. That will push the address of `'h'` onto the stack.

Pushing `'he'` (with something like `push word [message]` or `push word ptr [message]`), OTOH, may be not what you really want. I see no good reason for passing only 2 characters of a string using the stack. It makes more sense to pass the address of the first character instead.

Comment: so message defined as a byte is just pointing to the first byte of whatever string a write?